# Build select form with jquery using a hrefs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a "simple" language selector that will work on  using jQuery.

I am aware that I also could build it using standard HTML with a form select and , but to my understanding, building a select form with OnClick location.ref values to jump to the URL is not very SEO friendly.

The reason is that when viewing the webpage from a mobile device, I would like to trigger the e.g. iPhone Wheel selector instead of a long list.

The idea:

Having a list of countries all inside their own  like this:

```
<div id="countryselector">
<ul>
 <li><a href="/cz/"><img src="/language/CZ.png"  alt="Czech" title="Czech" class="landeflag"/> - Czech</a></li>
    <li><a href="/dk/"><img src="/language/DK.png"  alt="Danish" title="Danish" class="landeflag"/> - Danish</a></li>
    <li><a href="/fi/"><img src="/language/FI.png"  alt="Finnish" title="Finnish" class="landeflag"/> - Finnish</a></li>
    <li><a href="/fr/"><img src="/language/FR.png"  alt="French" title="French" class="landeflag"/> - French</a></li>
    <li><a href="/de/"><img src="/language/DE.png"  alt="Deutsch" title="Deutsch" class="landeflag"/> - Deutsch</a></li>
    <li><a href="/it/"><img src="/language/IT.png"  alt="Italian" title="Italian" class="landeflag"/> - Italian</a></li>
    <li><a href="/no/"><img src="/language/NO.png"  alt="Norwegian" title="Norwegian" class="landeflag"/> - Norwegian</a></li>
    <li><a href="/pl/"><img src="/language/PL.png"  alt="Polish" title="Polish" class="landeflag"/> - Polish</a></li>
    <li><a href="/pt/"><img src="/language/PT.png"  alt="Portuguese" title="Portuguese" class="landeflag"/> - Portuguese</a></li>
    <li><a href="/ru/"><img src="/language/RU.png"  alt="Russian" title="Russian" class="landeflag"/> - Russian</a></li>
    <li><a href="/es/"><img src="/language/ES.png"  alt="Spanish" title="Spanish" class="landeflag"/> - Spanish</a></li>
    <li><a href="/se/"><img src="/language/SE.png"  alt="Swedish" title="Swedish" class="landeflag"/> - Swedish</a></li>
    <li><a href="/tr/"><img src="/language/TR.png"  alt="Turkish" title="Turkish" class="landeflag"/> - Turkish</a></li>
    <li><a href="/en/"><img src="/language/EN.png"  alt="English" title="English" class="landeflag"/> - English</a></li>
    <li><a href="/us/"><img src="/language/US.png"  alt="American" title="American" class="landeflag"/> - American</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then having jquery to interpret the div and generating the list as form select options with links.

```
<script>
var $sel = $("<select/>")
  .appendTo("#countryselector")
  .change(function() {
    document.location.href = $sel.val();
  })
$("#countryselector a").each(function() {
  $("<option/>")
  .appendTo($sel)
  .val(this.href)
  .html(this.innerHTML)
});
</script>
```

The jQuery code is a piece of code I have found in my search for a solution. Unfortunately I am not that into jQuery, so I hope someone can lead me on the way.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this JSfiddle, I suppose this is what you asked for.
Notice that I added an empty select field:

```
<select id="country-select-input"></select>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#countryselector a").each(function() {
  $("<option/>")
  .appendTo($("#country-select-input"))
  .val(this.href)
  .html(this.innerHTML)
});

$("#country-select-input").change(function(){
    alert($(this).val())   
});
```

[Example for Rendering form Select](https://jsfiddle.net/pjy7zdLe/)

Comment: Thanks @ahmed - it works fine with the way you have made it. I have added the location.href to the change function, so it automatcally changes the URL. One thing though - is it possible to hide the select box the way you did the links and replace it by an image, and when that image is clicked (touched on mobile device) it triggers the select?

Comment: Thanks again @ahmed but this does not trigger the select, it only shows it, so you still have to click it. What I'm trying to do is to have an image of the flag to the active country shown (which I'll get from an URL variable) - when from a mobile device you press this flag, the select triggers and e.g. the iPhone select wheel is activated (just as if you press the initial select box). Is this possible?

Comment: sorry for spamming with all my questions, but I have a final question :-) Is there any possibility to use a PHP $_GET or similar to get the jQuery made select to show the selected language instead of the first language in the list? in PHP I would do something like this inside a select: `if($_GET[language] == "en"){ echo "selected"; }` is this possible in jQuery?

Comment: Hi. For the $_GET option, You need to create a global variable like this RIGHT BEFORE the script we made above:
<script>
selectedLanguage = "<?php echo $_GET['lan']; ?>"; 
</script>
And use that variable inside the above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This  

    <script>
    var options="";
    $("#countryselector a").each(function(){
    options +="<option value='"+$(this).attr('href')+"' >"+$(this).html()+"</option>";
    });
    $("#countryselector").after("<select id='customSelect'>"+options+"</select>");
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks @muhammad atif - I went with ahmed's answer but yours worked too. Due to my lack of jQuery/javascript experience, it was easier for me to add workable links in the select in the above answer. Thanks again.